# asp.net server.execute

Tags: asp.net

I am using server.execute to call a another form my code Looks like this

```
<div>
<% server.execute("default2.aspx") %>
</div>
```

My problem is the size of the default2.aspx is greater so when i apply height to the div  the default2.aspx is overlapping the other content in the default page

Answer (score 1):

Is not setting the height an option? Typically if the height is not set it's default is "auto"

You could also use:

```
div
{
height:500px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

If the content is too big for the area, a scrollbar will appear.

Using your code:

```
<div style="height:500px;overflow: auto;">
<% server.execute("default2.aspx") %>
</div>
```